# How to set an onClickListener to multiple Buttons through an ArrayAdapter [Android]

Tags: android, button, onclick, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener

How do I set an onClickListener to multiple Buttons through an ArrayAdapter?

Bare in mind that I need the buttons to:
 --A: kill the Activity that holds the ArrayAdapter and one starts a new Activity.
 --B: begin a new Activity

Here is my relevant code:

**Holding Activity**

```
public class MenuActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private LinkedList<Button> menuList;
private MenuButtonArrayAdapter menuButtonArrayAdapter;
private Button newGameButton, exitGameButton, continueGameButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    initialize();

    setUpMenu();
}

private void initialize()
{
    //Get references to fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    MainMenuFragment menuFragment = (MainMenuFragment)fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.MainMenuFragment);

    //Initialize list
    menuList = new LinkedList<Button>();

    //Create an ArrayAdapter to bind the List to ListViews
    menuButtonArrayAdapter = new MenuButtonArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.main_menu_button_layout, menuList);

    newGameButton = new Button(this);
    exitGameButton = new Button(this);
    newGameButton.setText("New game");
    exitGameButton.setText("Exit");

    menuFragment.setListAdapter(menuButtonArrayAdapter);
}

private void setUpMenu()
{

    menuList.add(newGameButton);
    menuList.add(exitGameButton);

    menuButtonArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

**ArrayAdapter**

```
 public class MenuButtonArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Button>{

private int resource;

public MenuButtonArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Button> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.resource = resource;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LinearLayout menuView;

    final String text = getItem(position).getText().toString();

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        menuView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
        layoutInflater.inflate(resource, menuView, true);
    }
    else menuView = (LinearLayout) convertView;

    Button b = (Button)menuView.findViewById(R.id.main_menu_button);
    b.setText(text);

    return menuView;
}
```

}

Comment: The problem is I cannot seem to find a way for me to set an OnClickListeners to the buttons which will close the Activity that uses the ArrayAdapter.

So for example one of my buttons "exitGameButton" will need to call the finish() method to end the MenuActivity.

Answer (score 0):

This way is not recommended but if you insist on achieving this way, you can set tag to button and according to different tags you can easily separate two or more buttons.

Comment: Why would you not recommend doing it this way? What do you recommend? Would really appreciate your help mate!